# VS 2015 Database Project: Data for new non-nullable data field

Tags: visual-studio-2015, database-project

I am adding a new non-nullable, no default value column to a table. I would like this column be populated via sql statement run during deployment.

How can I get arbitrary data into this non-nullable column during deployment?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to add it something like this in the table definition:

CREATE TABLE (... existing stuff
, NewColumn INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_MyTable_NewColumn DEFAULT 0
... )

You can then use a post-deploy script to change that value to whatever you want.  Alternatively, you could set it to NULL when adding the column and update in a post-deploy script. If you need it to be NOT NULL, your best bet is to choose a decent default and then update the table afterwards.